# C# Form Dynamic Controls

Tags: c#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DENEME1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text += "1 ";
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text += "2 ";
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text += "3 ";
            }
            else if (radioButton4.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text += "4 ";
            }
            .....
            .....
            .....
            .....
        }
    }   
}
```

[image]

If i have more than 10 radio buttons how can i control which one are selected. I tried it like above but i think that it isn't the correct way. How can i make it better? For example if i have 100 radio buttons how can i get the selected one?

Comment: In your event handler the `sender`  argument is exacly the radio button (or other control) which was clicked. So, you can just check the value and act accordingly.  By the way, if you interested in the `Checked` state, may be it will be better to use `CheckedChanged` event instead of `Click` event

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option

- RadioButtons are in panels (border is to show this)
- Originally each RadioButton text was radioButton**n**
- There is no logic here to decide which RadioButton may or may not be checked, only provides a list to work with.

[image]

String extension needed

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Numbers(this string sender) =>
        Regex.Replace(sender, "[^0-9 _]", "");

}
```

Control extensions

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this Control control) where T : class
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            T thisControl = child as T;
            if (thisControl != null)
            {
                yield return (T)thisControl;
            }

            if (child.HasChildren)
            {
                foreach (T descendant in Descendants<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    public static List<RadioButton> RadioButtonList(this Control control) => 
        control.Descendants<RadioButton>().ToList();
    
    public static List<RadioButton> RadioButtonListChecked(this Control control) => 
        control.RadioButtonList().Where(rb => rb.Checked).ToList();

}
```

Form code

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private List<RadioButton> _checkedRadioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RadioButtonList().ForEach(rb =>
        {
            rb.CheckedChanged += OnCheckedChanged;
            rb.Checked = false;
            rb.Text = rb.Text.Numbers(); // original names are radioButton1, radioButton2 etc
        });

        label1.Text = "";
    }

    private void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessChecked(sender);
    }

    private void ProcessChecked(object sender)
    {
        if (!(sender is RadioButton radioButton) || !radioButton.Checked) return;

        _checkedRadioButtons = this.RadioButtonListChecked();
        
        if (_checkedRadioButtons.Count > 0)
        {
            label1.Text = string.Join(" ", 
                _checkedRadioButtons.Select(rb => rb.Text));
        }
    }

    private void RadioButtonsCheckedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_checkedRadioButtons.Any())
        {
            var checkedList = _checkedRadioButtons.Select(rb => rb).ToArray();
            var names = string.Join("\n", checkedList.Select(rb => rb.Name));

            MessageBox.Show(names);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code dynamically checks whether the control is `RadioButton` and then fetches the RadioButton name number and displays it on the label.

```
foreach (Control ctr in this.Controls)
{
   if (ctr is RadioButton)
   {
       RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)ctr;
       if (radioButton.Checked)
       {
           //get number in radioButton
           string num = "";
           foreach(Char c in radioButton.Name)
           {
              if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                 num += c;
           }
           label1.Text += num + " ";
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label1.Text += Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Checked)?.Text;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.